# What do I say when someone says "hi"

Tags: greetings

I am from spain and I want to know what to say when someone says "Hi". I have taken many english classes. Should I say "Hi" back?

Comment: It would be usual to follow it with some other phrase otherwise it sounds a bit short just as, I suspect, you would not just reply Hola with Hola. There are too many options to list.

Comment: If you're in North America, and you're both under 50, say, "What's up?" If you're in the UK, say "You alright?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to say "hi" than saying "hi" back would be fine, but usually people say things like "hi, how are you"